# execute function after a button click FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a button which pushes some data to a List, and another function which displays data to the page, data are pushed to the list once the button is clicked but it does not appear on a screen unless I press R to refresh it.
So I need some lifecycle method or whatever to make it work.

```
  final List<TextEditingController> _controllers = [];

  void onButtonPress() {
    TextEditingController newController = TextEditingController();
    _controllers.add(newController);
  }


  displayTextFields(device) {
    var children = <Widget>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < _controllers.length; i++) {
      children.add(
        TextField(
          controller: _controllers[i],
        ),
      );
    }

    return Column(
      children: children,
    );
  }


...

return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Click Button '),
            onPressed: onButtonPress,
          ),
        ),
        displayTextFields(device),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have to use a `StatefulWidget`. I don't know what type of widget are you using, se the docs [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive#stateful-and-stateless-widgets).

After this, what you have to do is next:

```
List<TextEditingController> _controllers = [];

  void onButtonPress() {
    TextEditingController newController = TextEditingController();
    _controllers.add(newController);

    setState() {
      _controllers = List.from(_controllers)..add(newController);
    }
  }
  displayTextFields(device) {
    var children = <Widget>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < _controllers.length; i++) {
      children.add(
        TextField(
          controller: _controllers[i],
        ),
      );
    }
    return Column(
      children: children,
    );
  }

...
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Clicl Button'),
            onPressed: onButtonPress,
          ),
        ),
        displayTextFields(device),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your method to,

```
    displayTextFields(device) {
        var children = <Widget>[];
        for (var i = 0; i < _controllers.length; i++) {
          children.add(
            TextField(
              controller: _controllers[i],
            ),
          );
    }

    return Column(
      children: children,
    );

    setState(() {
    });
}
```

I hope this helps.